# Fill area within two line

Tags: qgis, area, fill

EdI'm a completely new user to QGIS, using version 2.12.

I'm trying to built a map featuring a quite large river. The waterway layer displays all streams in the area, plus the edges of the river, which I'd like to fill in to make the map a bit clearer and have a neat border.

Anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Are these actually line layers or polygon? It looks like you may just need to apply a symbology to the river polygons?

Comment: To me it's just lines and the only thing I can do is modify the thickness of these lines, which is not what I want as it affects all the streams around. Can I select the lines, create a polygon and fill it up? If yes, I'm affraid I'd need a step-by-step procedure...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: In the _Processing Toolbox_, there is the SAGA tool **Convert Lines to Polygons**. You can try selecting the lines and use the tool to create a polygon using the lines as the boundary.